# MetaModelUnstructured Component Optimization

Tags: openmdao

I am missing a point on how to get the 'output' out of a metamodel that is being used as a component in the problem.
It is clear the compute part should have an  output but how.  Below is the simple sin function as a metamodelunstructured component. I tried to modify the samples. But the error is :

> File
>   "C:\Users\ebarlas\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\group.py",
>   line 201, in _setup_procs
>       subsys._setup_procs(subsys.name, sub_comm)
>
> TypeError: _setup_procs() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'comm'

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, IndepVarComp
from openmdao.api import  ScipyOptimizeDriver
from openmdao.api import  MetaModelUnStructured, FloatKrigingSurrogate
# Below class syntax is not working 
class trig(MetaModelUnStructured):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', 0., training_data=np.linspace(0,10,20))
        self.add_output('sin_x', 0., surrogate=FloatKrigingSurrogate(), 
                        training_data=.5*np.sin(np.linspace(0,10,20)))

        self.declare_partials(of='sin_x', wrt='x', method='fd')
# If I uncomment 4 lines below and comment out the class above it works fine.
#trig = MetaModelUnStructured()
#trig.add_input('x', 0., training_data=np.linspace(0,10,20))
#trig.add_output('sin_x', 0., surrogate=FloatKrigingSurrogate(), 
#                training_data=.5*np.sin(np.linspace(0,10,20)))
#trig.declare_partials(of='sin_x', wrt='x', method='fd')

prob = Problem()
inputs_comp = IndepVarComp()
inputs_comp.add_output('x',  5)
prob.model.add_subsystem('inputs_comp', inputs_comp)
prob.model.add_subsystem('trig', trig)

prob.model.connect('inputs_comp.x', 'trig.x')

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'COBYLA'

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-3
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.model.add_design_var('inputs_comp.x', lower=4, upper=7)
prob.model.add_objective('trig.sin_x')

prob.setup(check=True)

prob.run_driver()

print(prob['trig.sin_x'])
print(prob['trig.x'])
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't implement the `compute` function for a MetaModel (outputs are predicted not computed).

See the docs here: http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/metamodelunstructured.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the compute to show my problem of accessing to the output from the optimizer or lets say putting the output out of that class. Omitting the ''compute'' does not fix the problem. To clarify, i have modified the code snippet. Please check it out to see what i mean, The four lines commented and uncommented are the part where i am confused. I am trying to understand where the training data should take place for the metamodel when it is in a class. Should that be within setup or initialize etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MetaModelUnstructured` component incorrectly, but there is another bug getting in the way first.

The class `trig` you've defined is not the same thing as the instance named `trig` in your commented out code. One is a class, the other is an instance. You can't pass a class into add_subsystem.

However, even fixing that problem there is still a bug in MetaModelUnstructured when its sub-classed. We'll get a fix in before OpenMDAO 2.3, but for now the way you've done it in the commented out code will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A quick follow up: is it possible to use the newly developed surrogate models in http://smt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A quick follow up: is it possible to use the newly developed surrogate models in [link](http://smt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
as a component too? Or would that need to be a external code component in openmdao. A gradient enhanced kriging seems useful if the gradients can also be fed into the openmdao optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the clarification to the question.  Note that the error in your updated example is for passing the class definition `trig` instead of an instance, but after correcting that I can see the problem.

This is a bug in `MetaModelUnStructured`... this will be fixed shortly.